# How to recap cell into column where the data is shown in rows

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, filter, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

Sorry for the bad subject title but I have a sheet #1 like this

```
A        B        C       D       E      F      G
Invoice  Fruit    Price   Fruit   Price  Fruit  Price
101      Apple    10      Orange  30     Mango  40
102      Orange   30      Pear    20     Berry  10
103      Melon    50      Apple   10     Berry  10
104      Pear     20      Melon   50     Apple  10
```

which basically detailing what fruits inside the invoice, but in columns

Then i want to have another sheet #2 to look like this

```
A        B        C        D
Inv      Price    Fruit:   Apple
101      10
103      10
104      10
```

So basically sheet #2 is a recap from sheet #1 where cell D1 will be the deciding factor which fruits recap will be shown in column A & B

Any ideas about what formula for cell A2:A and B2:B in sheet #2 ?

Comment: Would you please share a copy of your spreadsheet (excluding private or confidential information) and including an example of a successful outcome. In this case, please provide the successful outcome for the entire sheet#1 (per the question);

Comment: Would I be right in saying that the next recap on sheet #2 could be Oranges, and it would say Inv 101, Price 30; Inv 102, price 30. Then presumably every fruit is summarised in this way.

Comment: hi sorry for late reply, i was out for business trip. our spreadsheet is a total mess, so i think the example above is the best way to simplify it.
your 2nd inquiry is totally right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY({A1:C10; A1:A10, D1:E10; A1:A10, F1:G10}, "select Col1,Col3 where Col2='"&D13&"'", 1)
```

[image: 0]

Comment: hi, thank you very much for the answer, i am having difficulties replicating the answer since i don't understand this part

{A1:C10; A1:A10, D1:E10; A1:A10, F1:G10}

would you mind elaborating the background of choosing this cell range?

thanks for caring

Comment: sure, we create virtual array/table using curly brackets `{ }` inside them when we use a comma `,` it means to put the next range next to it eg. side-by-side. if we use a semicolon `;` it means to put the next range under it eg. in the same column. (note that matrix needs to be always of the same size - so if you put up 3 columns then under it needs to be a range again only with 3 columns. same applies for rows). so to break it down we combine A column with every Fruit and Price column. goal is to put all prices in the same column and all fruits in the same column keeping  Invoice for each row

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind patience while sharing the explanation!